# Can Devexpress Javascript Intellisense use with ClientInstanceName

Tags: devexpress, intellisense

[Devexpress Javascript Intellisense](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2010/04/20/how-to-get-devexpress-javascript-intellisense.aspx) is a very nice feature but it seems that it can cast object only when it came as function argument. can i refer control like ASPxClientComboBox by ClientInstanceName and get it work with this intellisense. I can't made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8122

I missed it. it has been provided in the manual.